# Codeigniter emails are not sending in AWS EC2

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2

I trying send email in a Codeigniter project. Earlier the domain was hosted in some other server, then the email were sending. Now I hosted my domain to AWS EC2, now the email are not sending.

**Code:**

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->from($from_email, 'Stackoverflow');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. Answers will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Why you marked as a duplicate. I'm facing this issue only in AWS. In other servers it working fine.

Comment: You need to setup a mail server in AWS. or use SMTP (PHPMailer Library)